# how to get responseString when JSON failed with AFJSONRequestOperation

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nshttpurlresponse

I'm having difficulties to get `responseString` when server failed to send a valid JSON response (fe. php echos some temp variable or something went wrong). I am using `AFJSONRequestOperation` from `AFNetwoking` like this:

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"object: %@", responseObject);
    }
    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id responseString) {
        NSLog(@"failure: %@", responseString);
    }
];
```

`responseString` is case of failure is always `nil`. When I tried to read the documentation (http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.1/Classes/AFJSONRequestOperation.html#//api/name/JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:) I've found that there is written that failure gets three arguments (but in reality four, the fourth being always nil). Is there any simple way to get the response as a string in that case?

Comment: What response are you getting on failure.

Comment: What is the content length indicated by the response object?

Comment: 2013-08-02 21:06:12.250 app[44769:c07] <0x7b3d720 ISWebServiceManager.m:(79)> responseCode: 200, error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.) (null)

how to get content length from response?

Comment: Maybe it's a bit off-topic, but when this happens to me, I always use cURL to test the server request and print the output in the terminal. This helps me to catch the possible echo's or notices.

Answer (score 0):

If `responseString` is `nil`, then you either didn't receive any data from the server, or the data could not be used to create a valid `NSString` object.

By the sound of your `Cocoa error 3840`, which corresponds to an `NSJSONSerialization` error, my guess is that the server was indeed sending back an empty response.

Comment: unfortunately not whole of your answer is true, JSON serialization fails, but the response is not empty (I even tried putting in webservice something like print('something'); die(); and the responseString is always nil...)

Comment: @patryk How are you checking the response? Are you using `curl`? Sniffing the incoming HTTP traffic in the simulator using Charles.app, Wireshark, or something similar?

Comment: I'm using GraphicalHTTPClient (available in appstore) with the same request parameters as AFNetworking call.

Comment: @patryk Without sniffing traffic, you can't be entirely sure about the particular details of the outgoing request. It's not just parameters: request headers are significant too. I would encourage you to use a more comprehensive tool to validate everything.

Comment: In that case GraphicalHTTPClient is sufficient, because i know that there is something in response (because when I get proper JSON success method gives proper object and when I type print('something') to spoil the request responseString in failure method is empty...).